# VS Code not running C

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't for the life of me get VSC to run C programs. The code in question runs correctly on Replit.

[Extension installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohYMn.png)

[GCC installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY5DJ.png)
(GCC file path was added to the windows environment)

I tried uninstalling and re-installing. And...

[It says I need a C extension.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8RSZ.png)

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You still have to configure vscode well, as said in the [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw).

If C\C++ extension is installed it will be asked to configure it for debugging or building, just follow the documentation.
But it is still not running, execute your program in the terminal with the gcc command: `gcc filename+extension -o filenameExe`

Comment: Even after following your advice, this does not work. No matter what command I type into terminal after creating task.json, it will not create a .exe (build finished with errors). At this point, the terminal is showing debug errors that do not exist on other IDE's.

Comment: Show us the errors given by gcc

Comment: PS C:\Users\ztayl\Desktop\Coding\CS1\Osmanagement> gcc OSManagement.c -o OSManagement.exe
OSManagement.c: In function 'memoryManagement':
OSManagement.c:170:4: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
    case First:
    ^~~~
OSManagement.c:174:4: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
    case Best:
OSManagement.c:178:4: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
    case Worst:
PS C:\Users\ztayl\Desktop\Coding\CS1\Osmanagement>

Comment: There are errors in your code. The gcc command works properly.

Comment: Then why does my code work in other IDE's? That cannot be the issue.

Comment: You have a compilation error with gcc command in the terminal or with vscode extension? I had an error with the extension but the compilation was working properly with gcc manually in the terminal.

Comment: I don't know why, but I tried running the program through the right click menu, and it worked. I'm not sure why the right click is working but the terminal is not. At this point, I am hard pressed to continue troubleshooting since I've got something that works.

Comment: Right click menu ? So it compiles with an extension